# Understanding const

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++14, constants

If you want to write an iterator, you usually write

```
T* operator->() const;
```

My problem is understanding this "const" with pointers and reference.

For instance, you can write the following struct:

```
struct A{
   int* x;

   A(int& x0):x{&x0}{}
   int* ptr() const {return x;}
   int& ref() const {return *x;}
};
```

And you can use it this way:

```
int x = 10;
const A a{x};

int& r = a.ref();
int* p = a.ptr();

*p = 4;
cout << x << endl;   // prints 4

r = 25;
cout << x << endl;  // prints 25
```

But why this compiles and works right (at least with g++ and clang). Why?

As I defined

```
const A a{x};
```

this "a" is const. So when I call

```
int* p = a.ptr();
```

I am calling ptr() with a const object, so the internal pointer A->x must be "int * const". But I am returning a "int *" without const. Why is this correct?

And what happens with the reference? If I call A::ref() with a "const A", what's the type this function returns? Something like "int& const"??? <--- I suppose this is the same as "int&".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always copy a const thing.

Answer (score 10):

There is a different between bitwise const and logical const.

When you have a `const A`, you can't modify its `int*` member. But there's a difference between modifying the member itself (*which* `int` that `x` points to) and modifying through the member (the value of the `int` that `x` points to). Those are different kinds of `const`. In the simplest case:

```
struct Ptr { int* p; };

int i = 42;
const Ptr ptr{&i};
*ptr.p = 57;
```

`ptr.p` still points to `i`, nothing changed there, so the `const` mechanic is enforced. But it's not logically `const` since you still changed something through a `const` object. The language doesn't enforce that for you though. That's up to you as the library writer.

If you want to *propagate* `const`-ness, you just provide an interface that is logically `const`:

```
int const* ptr() const {return x;}
int const& ref() const {return *x;}
//  ^^^^^
```

Now, users can't modify through your `const A` both bitwise (can't change what `x` points to) and logically (can't change that value of that pointee either).

Answer (score 3):

> But why this compiles and works right (at least with g++ and clang). Why?

Because the program is well formed and has defined behaviour. Const correctness was not violated.

> I am calling ptr() with a const object, so the internal pointer A->x must be "int * const". But I am returning a "int *" without const. Why is this correct?

Because it is completely OK to make copies of const objects. Those copies need not to be const. Copying an object does not make modifications to the original object (assuming there is no user defined copy constructor that does silly things).

> And what happens with the reference? If I call A::ref() with a "const A", what's the type this function returns?

`int& ref()` always returns `int&`. Just like `int* ptr()` always returns `int*`.

> Something like "int& const"???

There is no such thing like `int& const`. References cannot have top level qualifiers (they can never be re-assigned).

Comment: Where do you see a copy being made? Both `ref()` and `ptr()` are returning a non-const reference or pointer to a member variable. Since the object is const, modifying its member in this way could lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom Neither returns a reference or a pointer to the member variable. `ptr` returns a *copy* of a member variable (that's where I see a copy; another copy is in the initialization of `p` with the return value from that function) and `ref` returns a reference to the object pointed by the member variable. You cannot modify the member using those functions. I see no UB in the code in the question.

Comment: OK, I see your point - it was a reading comprehension problem on my end. I was confused by the number of levels of indirection. Since `int x = 10` is *not* const, and the object is keeping a pointer to that external variable, there's no undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom indeed. And if `x` was const, the program would be ill-formed because the constructor takes a non-const reference. A bigger potential for problem than constness is the possibility of returning a copy of `A` which points to a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

In `struct A`, when you make an instance of it `const`, you make the pointer constant, *but that doesn't automatically make the pointed-to object constant*.

Declaring something like `const A a(ref);` is basically equivalent to invoking the following code:

```
struct A_const {
    int * const x;

    A(int& x0):x{&x0}{}
    int* ptr() const {return x;}
    int& ref() const {return *x;}
};
```

If you remember your pointer rules, this means that `x` is a constant pointer, which means it cannot be made to point to something else (it's functionally similar to a reference, but can be `null`), but critically, *the `int` that it is pointing to is not constant*, which means nothing stops you from writing something like this:

```
int val = 17;
const A a(val);
*(a.val) = 19; //Totally valid, compiles, and behaves as expected!
int val2 = 13;
//a.val = &val2; //Invalid, will invoke compile-time error
```

This is also the reason why `std::unique_ptr<int>` and `std::unique_ptr<const int>` represent different objects.

If you want the pointed-to object to not be modifiable on a `const` object, you need to enforce that in the code itself. Since functions can be overloaded on the basis of whether the source object is `const` or not, that's pretty easy:

```
struct A {
    int * x;

    A(int& x0):x{&x0}{}
    int * ptr() {return x;}
    int & ref() {return *x;}
    int const* ptr() const {return x;}
    int const& ref() const {return *x;}
};

int val = 17;
A a(val);
a.ref() = 19;//Okay.
*a.ptr() = 4;//Okay.

const A b(val);
b.ref() = 13;//Compile error
*b.ptr() = 17;//Compile error
```